# Is the use of tense correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, ing

> John the Prince-the same John **would later seek** the hidden treasure in the Caribbeans-landed on Puerto Rico.

Should it be "seeking"? Since the action of seeking doesn't exist for only a instant.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these is correct, and common:

> John the Prince-the same John who would later seek the hidden treasure in
> the Caribbeans-landed on Puerto Rico.
>
> John the Prince-the same John who later sought the hidden treasure in
> the Caribbeans-landed on Puerto Rico.

I can't think of how 'seeking' would be correct.

The *who* in these examples is not strictly needed, but it's unusual to omit it.

Comment: You could say *would later be seeking*.

Answer (score 0):

Both *would seek* and *would be seeking* are correct answers in this sentence.

I can't think of *seeking* be correct.